# Bootstrap on mobile device (not rendering causing hanging problems)

Tags: highcharts, bootstrap-4

I wondering what's the problem with this page https://jsfiddle.net/3r2eo617/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="">

    <title>Demo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <main role="main" class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-primary text-white">Record</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="container">
                        <b>Filename</b><br>acc.dat<br><br>
                        <b>Time Step</b><br>0.02 s<br><br>
                        <b>No Points</b><br>2400
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="highchart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="highchart2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="highchart3" style="min-width: 310px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<pre id="csv_acc" style="display:none">Time,Acceleration
        0.000,0.0000
        0.020,0.0000
        0.040,0.0000
        0.060,0.0000
        0.080,0.0000
        0.100,0.0000
        0.120,0.0000
        0.140,0.0000
        0.160,0.0000
        0.180,0.0000
        0.200,0.0000
        0.220,0.0000
        0.240,0.0000
        0.260,0.0000
        0.280,0.0000
        0.300,0.0000
        0.320,0.0000
        0.340,0.0000
        0.360,0.0000
        0.380,0.0000
        0.400,0.0000
        0.420,0.0000
        0.440,0.0000
        0.460,0.0000
        0.480,0.0000
        0.500,0.0000
        0.520,0.0000
        0.540,0.0000
        0.560,0.0000
        0.580,0.0000
        0.600,0.0000
        0.620,0.0000
        0.640,0.0000
        0.660,0.0000
        0.680,0.0000
        0.700,0.0000
        0.720,0.0000
        0.740,0.0000
        0.760,0.0000
        0.780,0.0000
        0.800,0.0000
        0.820,0.0000
        0.840,0.0000
        0.860,0.0000
        0.880,0.0000
        0.900,0.0000
        0.920,0.0000
        0.940,0.0000
        0.960,0.0000
        0.980,0.0000
        1.000,0.0000
        1.020,0.0000
        1.040,0.0000
        1.060,0.0000
        1.080,0.0000
        1.100,0.0000
        1.120,0.0000
        1.140,0.0000
        1.160,0.0000
        1.180,0.0000
        1.200,0.0000
        1.220,0.0000
        1.240,0.0000
        1.260,0.0000
        1.280,0.0000
        1.300,0.0000
        1.320,0.0000
        1.340,0.0000
        1.360,0.0000
        1.380,0.0000
        1.400,0.0000
        1.420,0.0000
        1.440,0.0000
        1.460,0.0000
        1.480,0.0000
        1.500,0.0000
        1.520,0.0000
        1.540,0.0000
        1.560,0.0000
        1.580,0.0000
        1.600,0.0000
        1.620,0.0000
        1.640,0.0000
        1.660,0.0000
        1.680,0.0000
        1.700,0.0000
        1.720,0.0000
        1.740,0.0000
        1.760,0.0000
        1.780,0.0000
        1.800,0.0000
        1.820,0.0000
        1.840,0.0000
        1.860,0.0000
        1.880,0.0000
        1.900,0.0000
        1.920,0.0000
        1.940,0.0000
        1.960,0.0000
        1.980,0.0000
        2.000,0.0000
        2.020,0.0000
        2.040,0.0000
        2.060,0.0000
        2.080,0.0000
        2.100,0.0000
        2.120,0.0000
        2.140,0.0000
        2.160,0.0000
        2.180,0.0000
        2.200,0.0000
        2.220,0.0000
        2.240,0.0000
        2.260,0.0000
        2.280,0.0000
        2.300,0.0000
        2.320,-0.0000
        2.340,-0.0000
        2.360,-0.0000
        2.380,-0.0000
        2.400,-0.0000
        2.420,-0.0000
        2.440,-0.0000
        2.460,0.0000
        2.480,0.0000
        2.500,0.0000
        2.520,0.0000
        2.540,0.0000
        2.560,0.0000
        2.580,0.0000
        2.600,-0.0000
        2.620,-0.0000
        2.640,-0.0000
        2.660,-0.0000
        2.680,-0.0000
        2.700,-0.0000
        2.720,-0.0000
        2.740,0.0000
        2.760,0.0000
        2.780,0.0000
        2.800,0.0000
        2.820,0.0000
        2.840,0.0000
        2.860,0.0000
        2.880,0.0000
        2.900,-0.0000
        2.920,-0.0000
        2.940,-0.0000
        2.960,-0.0000
        2.980,-0.0000
        3.000,-0.0000
        3.020,-0.0000
        3.040,-0.0000
        3.060,0.0000
        3.080,0.0000
        3.100,0.0000
        3.120,0.0000
        3.140,0.0000
        3.160,0.0000
        3.180,0.0000
        3.200,0.0000
        3.220,0.0000
        3.240,0.0000
        3.260,0.0000
        3.280,0.0000
        3.300,-0.0000
        3.320,-0.0000
        3.340,-0.0000
        3.360,-0.0000
        3.380,-0.0000
        3.400,-0.0000
        3.420,-0.0000
        3.440,0.0000
        3.460,0.0000
        3.480,0.0000
        3.500,0.0000
        3.520,0.0000
        3.540,0.0000
        3.560,0.0000
        3.580,0.0000
        3.600,-0.0000
        3.620,-0.0000
        3.640,-0.0000
        3.660,-0.0000
        3.680,-0.0001
        3.700,-0.0002
        3.720,-0.0002
        3.740,-0.0002
        3.760,-0.0002
        3.780,-0.0001
        3.800,-0.0001
        3.820,-0.0001
        3.840,-0.0000
        3.860,-0.0002
        3.880,-0.0005
        3.900,-0.0008
        3.920,-0.0005
        3.940,-0.0004
        3.960,-0.0006
        3.980,-0.0002
        4.000,0.0005
        4.020,0.0005
        4.040,-0.0001
        4.060,-0.0011
        4.080,-0.0016
        4.100,-0.0009
        4.120,-0.0001
        4.140,-0.0004
        4.160,-0.0001
        4.180,0.0021
        4.200,0.0022
        4.220,-0.0012
        4.240,-0.0038
        4.260,-0.0033
        4.280,-0.0020
        4.300,-0.0023
        4.320,-0.0012
        4.340,0.0005
        4.360,0.0000
        4.380,-0.0025
        4.400,-0.0056
        4.420,-0.0031
        4.440,0.0023
        4.460,0.0036
        4.480,0.0034
        4.500,0.0066
        4.520,0.0094
        4.540,0.0056
        4.560,0.0045
        4.580,0.0026
        4.600,-0.0046
        4.620,-0.0077
        4.640,0.0004
        4.660,0.0105
        4.680,0.0014
        4.700,-0.0058
        4.720,0.0031
        4.740,0.0112
        4.760,0.0171
        4.780,0.0257
        4.800,0.0265
        4.820,0.0128
        4.840,0.0006
        4.860,-0.0034
        4.880,-0.0020
        4.900,0.0090
        4.920,0.0003
        4.940,-0.0323
        4.960,-0.0390
        4.980,-0.0281
        5.000,-0.0170

    </pre>
<pre id="csv_vel" style="display:none">Time,Velocity
        0.000,0.0000
        0.020,0.0000
        0.040,0.0001
        0.060,0.0001
        0.080,0.0001
        0.100,0.0002
        0.120,0.0002
        0.140,0.0002
        0.160,0.0002
        0.180,0.0003
        0.200,0.0003
        0.220,0.0003
        0.240,0.0004
        0.260,0.0004
        0.280,0.0004
        0.300,0.0004
        0.320,0.0005
        0.340,0.0005
        0.360,0.0005
        0.380,0.0005
        0.400,0.0006
        0.420,0.0006
        0.440,0.0006
        0.460,0.0007
        0.480,0.0007
        0.500,0.0007
        0.520,0.0007
        0.540,0.0008
        0.560,0.0008
        0.580,0.0008
        0.600,0.0008
        0.620,0.0009
        0.640,0.0009
        0.660,0.0009
        0.680,0.0009
        0.700,0.0009
        0.720,0.0010
        0.740,0.0010
        0.760,0.0010
        0.780,0.0010
        0.800,0.0010
        0.820,0.0011
        0.840,0.0011
        0.860,0.0011
        0.880,0.0011
        0.900,0.0012
        0.920,0.0012
        0.940,0.0012
        0.960,0.0012
        0.980,0.0012
        1.000,0.0012
        1.020,0.0013
        1.040,0.0013
        1.060,0.0013
        1.080,0.0013
        1.100,0.0013
        1.120,0.0014
        1.140,0.0014
        1.160,0.0014
        1.180,0.0014
        1.200,0.0014
        1.220,0.0015
        1.240,0.0015
        1.260,0.0015
        1.280,0.0015
        1.300,0.0015
        1.320,0.0015
        1.340,0.0015
        1.360,0.0016
        1.380,0.0016
        1.400,0.0016
        1.420,0.0016
        1.440,0.0016
        1.460,0.0016
        1.480,0.0016
        1.500,0.0017
        1.520,0.0017
        1.540,0.0017
        1.560,0.0017
        1.580,0.0017
        1.600,0.0017
        1.620,0.0017
        1.640,0.0018
        1.660,0.0018
        1.680,0.0018
        1.700,0.0018
        1.720,0.0018
        1.740,0.0018
        1.760,0.0018
        1.780,0.0018
        1.800,0.0018
        1.820,0.0019
        1.840,0.0019
        1.860,0.0019
        1.880,0.0019
        1.900,0.0019
        1.920,0.0019
        1.940,0.0019
        1.960,0.0019
        1.980,0.0019
        2.000,0.0019
        2.020,0.0019
        2.040,0.0020
        2.060,0.0020
        2.080,0.0020
        2.100,0.0020
        2.120,0.0020
        2.140,0.0020
        2.160,0.0020
        2.180,0.0020
        2.200,0.0020
        2.220,0.0020
        2.240,0.0020
        2.260,0.0020
        2.280,0.0020
        2.300,0.0021
        2.320,0.0021
        2.340,0.0021
        2.360,0.0021
        2.380,0.0021
        2.400,0.0021
        2.420,0.0021
        2.440,0.0021
        2.460,0.0021
        2.480,0.0021
        2.500,0.0021
        2.520,0.0021
        2.540,0.0021
        2.560,0.0021
        2.580,0.0021
        2.600,0.0022
        2.620,0.0021
        2.640,0.0021
        2.660,0.0021
        2.680,0.0021
        2.700,0.0021
        2.720,0.0021
        2.740,0.0021
        2.760,0.0021
        2.780,0.0022
        2.800,0.0022
        2.820,0.0022
        2.840,0.0022
        2.860,0.0022
        2.880,0.0022
        2.900,0.0022
        2.920,0.0022
        2.940,0.0022
        2.960,0.0022
        2.980,0.0022
        3.000,0.0021
        3.020,0.0021
        3.040,0.0021
        3.060,0.0021
        3.080,0.0021
        3.100,0.0021
        3.120,0.0021
        3.140,0.0021
        3.160,0.0022
        3.180,0.0022
        3.200,0.0022
        3.220,0.0022
        3.240,0.0022
        3.260,0.0022
        3.280,0.0022
        3.300,0.0022
        3.320,0.0022
        3.340,0.0022
        3.360,0.0022
        3.380,0.0021
        3.400,0.0021
        3.420,0.0021
        3.440,0.0021
        3.460,0.0021
        3.480,0.0021
        3.500,0.0021
        3.520,0.0021
        3.540,0.0022
        3.560,0.0022
        3.580,0.0022
        3.600,0.0022
        3.620,0.0022
        3.640,0.0021
        3.660,0.0021
        3.680,0.0019
        3.700,0.0016
        3.720,0.0013
        3.740,0.0009
        3.760,0.0005
        3.780,0.0003
        3.800,0.0001
        3.820,-0.0001
        3.840,-0.0002
        3.860,-0.0004
        3.880,-0.0011
        3.900,-0.0024
        3.920,-0.0037
        3.940,-0.0047
        3.960,-0.0057
        3.980,-0.0065
        4.000,-0.0061
        4.020,-0.0052
        4.040,-0.0048
        4.060,-0.0060
        4.080,-0.0086
        4.100,-0.0111
        4.120,-0.0120
        4.140,-0.0124
        4.160,-0.0129
        4.180,-0.0109
        4.200,-0.0065
        4.220,-0.0055
        4.240,-0.0104
        4.260,-0.0175
        4.280,-0.0228
        4.300,-0.0270
        4.320,-0.0305
        4.340,-0.0312
        4.360,-0.0307
        4.380,-0.0332
        4.400,-0.0413
        4.420,-0.0500
        4.440,-0.0508
        4.460,-0.0449
        4.480,-0.0379
        4.500,-0.0279
        4.520,-0.0118
        4.540,0.0032
        4.560,0.0133
        4.580,0.0204
        4.600,0.0185
        4.620,0.0062
        4.640,-0.0010
        4.660,0.0098
        4.680,0.0217
        4.700,0.0173
        4.720,0.0146
        4.740,0.0289
        4.760,0.0573
        4.780,0.1001
        4.800,0.1523
        4.820,0.1916
        4.840,0.2050
        4.860,0.2021
        4.880,0.1967
        4.900,0.2037
        4.920,0.2130
        4.940,0.1809
        4.960,0.1096
        4.980,0.0426
        5.000,-0.0024
    </pre>
<pre id="csv_dis" style="display:none">Time,Displacement
        0.000,0.0000
        0.020,0.0000
        0.040,0.0000
        0.060,0.0000
        0.080,0.0000
        0.100,0.0000
        0.120,0.0000
        0.140,0.0000
        0.160,0.0000
        0.180,0.0000
        0.200,0.0000
        0.220,0.0000
        0.240,0.0000
        0.260,0.0001
        0.280,0.0001
        0.300,0.0001
        0.320,0.0001
        0.340,0.0001
        0.360,0.0001
        0.380,0.0001
        0.400,0.0001
        0.420,0.0001
        0.440,0.0001
        0.460,0.0002
        0.480,0.0002
        0.500,0.0002
        0.520,0.0002
        0.540,0.0002
        0.560,0.0002
        0.580,0.0002
        0.600,0.0003
        0.620,0.0003
        0.640,0.0003
        0.660,0.0003
        0.680,0.0003
        0.700,0.0003
        0.720,0.0004
        0.740,0.0004
        0.760,0.0004
        0.780,0.0004
        0.800,0.0004
        0.820,0.0005
        0.840,0.0005
        0.860,0.0005
        0.880,0.0005
        0.900,0.0006
        0.920,0.0006
        0.940,0.0006
        0.960,0.0006
        0.980,0.0007
        1.000,0.0007
        1.020,0.0007
        1.040,0.0007
        1.060,0.0008
        1.080,0.0008
        1.100,0.0008
        1.120,0.0008
        1.140,0.0009
        1.160,0.0009
        1.180,0.0009
        1.200,0.0009
        1.220,0.0010
        1.240,0.0010
        1.260,0.0010
        1.280,0.0011
        1.300,0.0011
        1.320,0.0011
        1.340,0.0012
        1.360,0.0012
        1.380,0.0012
        1.400,0.0012
        1.420,0.0013
        1.440,0.0013
        1.460,0.0013
        1.480,0.0014
        1.500,0.0014
        1.520,0.0014
        1.540,0.0015
        1.560,0.0015
        1.580,0.0015
        1.600,0.0016
        1.620,0.0016
        1.640,0.0016
        1.660,0.0017
        1.680,0.0017
        1.700,0.0018
        1.720,0.0018
        1.740,0.0018
        1.760,0.0019
        1.780,0.0019
        1.800,0.0019
        1.820,0.0020
        1.840,0.0020
        1.860,0.0020
        1.880,0.0021
        1.900,0.0021
        1.920,0.0022
        1.940,0.0022
        1.960,0.0022
        1.980,0.0023
        2.000,0.0023
        2.020,0.0024
        2.040,0.0024
        2.060,0.0024
        2.080,0.0025
        2.100,0.0025
        2.120,0.0026
        2.140,0.0026
        2.160,0.0026
        2.180,0.0027
        2.200,0.0027
        2.220,0.0028
        2.240,0.0028
        2.260,0.0028
        2.280,0.0029
        2.300,0.0029
        2.320,0.0030
        2.340,0.0030
        2.360,0.0030
        2.380,0.0031
        2.400,0.0031
        2.420,0.0032
        2.440,0.0032
        2.460,0.0033
        2.480,0.0033
        2.500,0.0033
        2.520,0.0034
        2.540,0.0034
        2.560,0.0035
        2.580,0.0035
        2.600,0.0035
        2.620,0.0036
        2.640,0.0036
        2.660,0.0037
        2.680,0.0037
        2.700,0.0038
        2.720,0.0038
        2.740,0.0038
        2.760,0.0039
        2.780,0.0039
        2.800,0.0040
        2.820,0.0040
        2.840,0.0041
        2.860,0.0041
        2.880,0.0042
        2.900,0.0042
        2.920,0.0042
        2.940,0.0043
        2.960,0.0043
        2.980,0.0044
        3.000,0.0044
        3.020,0.0045
        3.040,0.0045
        3.060,0.0045
        3.080,0.0046
        3.100,0.0046
        3.120,0.0047
        3.140,0.0047
        3.160,0.0048
        3.180,0.0048
        3.200,0.0048
        3.220,0.0049
        3.240,0.0049
        3.260,0.0050
        3.280,0.0050
        3.300,0.0051
        3.320,0.0051
        3.340,0.0051
        3.360,0.0052
        3.380,0.0052
        3.400,0.0053
        3.420,0.0053
        3.440,0.0054
        3.460,0.0054
        3.480,0.0054
        3.500,0.0055
        3.520,0.0055
        3.540,0.0056
        3.560,0.0056
        3.580,0.0057
        3.600,0.0057
        3.620,0.0057
        3.640,0.0058
        3.660,0.0058
        3.680,0.0059
        3.700,0.0059
        3.720,0.0059
        3.740,0.0060
        3.760,0.0060
        3.780,0.0060
        3.800,0.0060
        3.820,0.0060
        3.840,0.0060
        3.860,0.0060
        3.880,0.0060
        3.900,0.0059
        3.920,0.0059
        3.940,0.0058
        3.960,0.0057
        3.980,0.0056
        4.000,0.0054
        4.020,0.0053
        4.040,0.0052
        4.060,0.0051
        4.080,0.0050
        4.100,0.0048
        4.120,0.0045
        4.140,0.0043
        4.160,0.0040
        4.180,0.0038
        4.200,0.0036
        4.220,0.0035
        4.240,0.0033
        4.260,0.0031
        4.280,0.0027
        4.300,0.0022
        4.320,0.0016
        4.340,0.0010
        4.360,0.0004
        4.380,-0.0003
        4.400,-0.0010
        4.420,-0.0019
        4.440,-0.0030
        4.460,-0.0039
        4.480,-0.0047
        4.500,-0.0054
        4.520,-0.0058
        4.540,-0.0059
        4.560,-0.0057
        4.580,-0.0054
        4.600,-0.0050
        4.620,-0.0047
        4.640,-0.0047
        4.660,-0.0046
        4.680,-0.0043
        4.700,-0.0039
        4.720,-0.0036
        4.740,-0.0031
        4.760,-0.0023
        4.780,-0.0007
        4.800,0.0018
        4.820,0.0053
        4.840,0.0092
        4.860,0.0133
        4.880,0.0173
        4.900,0.0213
        4.920,0.0255
        4.940,0.0294
        4.960,0.0323
        4.980,0.0338
        5.000,0.0342
</pre>
    </main>

    <footer class="footer py-3 bg-light">
        <div class="container text-center">
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Highcharts.chart('highchart', {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x',
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            data: {
                boostThreshold: 1,
                csv: document.getElementById('csv_acc').innerHTML
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: "Acceleration [g]",
                }
            }
        });

        Highcharts.chart('highchart2', {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'xy',
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            data: {
                boostThreshold: 1,
                csv: document.getElementById('csv_vel').innerHTML
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: "Velcocity [cm/s]",
                }
            }
        });

        Highcharts.chart('highchart3', {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'xy',
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            data: {
                boostThreshold: 1,
                csv: document.getElementById('csv_dis').innerHTML
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: "Displacement [cm]",
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

when viewed from a mobile device, although it can be viewed correctly in desktop devices. Specifically in mobile devices that running Android OS always causes "not responding symptom" in the latest versions of Chrome/Brave/Vivaldi Browsers.

Could anyone suggest me how this page can be accessed correctly through mobile devices without hanging problems?

Thanks in advance!

PS. The same problem exists when viewing this demo https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series from a mobile device, but not for the other demos.

Comment: if the issue exists on the demo from the official site, you should log a request with highcharts

Comment: How to log the request from a mobile device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you were trying to apply the boost module by setting boostThreshold property to 1. You were close, in this case, the boost module will fix the issue. Although to make it work you need to do two things - first you need to import boost module, then you should apply boostThreshold in a different place, for example in plotOptions.line.boostThreshold or in series.boostThreshold because you can't access this property from the place you were trying to apply it (data). After fixing those two things everything is working smoothly on my android device.

`<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>`

```
plotOptions: {
       line: {
         boostThreshold: 1
       }
     },
```

**Docs references:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module

**API references:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.boostThreshold

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q9805pv4/

Comment: Gorgeous! Works like a charm! I know that I was on the right way with boost. I know that I was on the right way by adding the boost module. Thanks for your accurate response Mat.